# Cloudflare Код ответа сервера 403 в яндексе и в google при обращении к сайту

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, сервер

Есть сайт на котором используется https://www.cloudflare.com/.
Сайт пользователю показывается как 200, вот пример через сервис https://checkmy.ru/

http://joxi.ru/v293N1BhzGvxjr

Но ботам поисковых систем он отдает код 403, вот примеры

http://joxi.ru/krDzxEBcJ0lal2 - Яндекс

http://joxi.ru/4AkgGYnIXMg6XA - Google

В чем проблема может быть проблема на стороне Cloudflare или хостинга и как ее можно исправить?

Comment: Как вариант можно добавить IP адреса ботов в белый список CloudFlare.

Comment: А какие это IP адреса и куда их нужно добавлять? В Firewall Rules настроено правило (cf.client.bot) Allow

Comment: Скриншоты надо загружать в сам вопрос.